# Random visible divs inside a table grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My situation** -
Within a 4x4 table grid (16 cells total), I'm trying to display up to 7 divs in their own individual cell (whichever div is visible, have it be in its own cell - 1 div per cell).

**What I need/My Question** - 
If divs "Test1", "Test3", "Test6" fade in, then have these divs display on a 3 different cells,..if 6 divs come in, 6 different cells, etc..

*Note:* The numbers appended after "Test" (Test0, Test1, etc.) are all being auto-generated and is actually 18 digits long (e.g., 123456789012345678), so I will never know the actual number. I was thinking of using the below function to find all the div id's containing "Test", place those results in the an array, and then somehow pull each result and append it to a random cell. But I'm not exactly sure how to go about it... :

```
 $("div[id^='Test']").each(function(n, i) {
        var id = this.id;      
    });
```

My main question - How can I display currently visible divs on their own cell?

**What I have tried** -
 
*My work in progress* : http://jsfiddle.net/xVDm9/

*Edit:* I commented out the black reappearing div out of the code as this might have been confusing and did not really make a case.

Comment: [New Fiddle with smaller divs so it's easier to see](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/wf8ZX/95/)

Comment: Not sure what this means, " I need this same scenario, but instead, with the visible divs that have faded in."

Comment: @Dale, Instead of having the black div in the cell, have one of the Test0-7 div's appear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to build. Hoewever, wouldn't it be easier to give **all** tablecells a div? And then fade those in and out? It would be faster than manipulating the DOM each time you want to show/hide a div.

This way, you could use the `:visible` selector to test if the selected div is already visible. If it is, fadeIn the next one.

Also, in some browsers, dynamically appending/mutating the table itself causes issues. Besides that, I'd recommend not using a table, but the following structure (it's easier to traverse and more scalable):

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
   <div class="tcell">
     <div id="yourUniqueID">
     </div>
   </div>
   <!-- ...repeat the div.tcell as often as you need -->
 </div>
```

and style it like so:

```
.tcell{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.33%; /* that's for 3 on a row, use whatever value you need */
}

.tcell > div{
  display: none; /* hide by default, since you'll be using jQuery to fadeIn/Out */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```